# Need to combine 2 mysql queries

Tags: mysql, select, count

So I want to determine how many hours have taken place since a period in time (compared to a timestamp) and then want to find out how many records I have since that timestamp (they're done hourly) and divide the two to get a percentage.   The two queries go like this:

Table design:

Historical --table
--ID --column with device id#
--TIME --DateTime Field with time entry was made

Query 1:

```
SELECT ID, min(TIME), timestampdiff(HOUR,NOW(), TIME) as uphours from Historical group by id
```

Query 2 (Despite how this query is written, I want it to do it for all the ID's in the table):

```
SELECT count(*) from Historical where ID 1
```

Then the final part would be:

```
uphours / secondQuery_return_value as Percentage
```

Can someone help me understand how to combine these queries?

Comment: can you post the schema for the table please, and I am not clear what you mean by "(Despite how this query is written, I want it to do it for all the ID's in the table)" - perhaps a little sample data and the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT ID, min(TIME), (timestampdiff(HOUR,NOW(), min(TIME))/count(*)) as Percentage
from Historical 
group by id
```

**Edit:** as Mark Bannister mentioned, it should make more sense to change `TIME` for `min(TIME)` on the percentage, otherwise it won't be the actual difference between now and the oldest time...

Comment: This looks really promising, let me give it a whirl.

Comment: And it works, excellent... now I wonder if I can combine two more... one more question and my work will be done.

Comment: @Damien.Bell I'm glad it works, and you should be able to combine as much as you want, just make sure they're grouped by the same criteria...

Comment: The new question is up, I'm stuck on the join aspect of it, it's getting to be pretty heinous... just trying to reduce the amount of queries that I'm making.

Comment: At the moment, `Percentage` will essentially be a random value since it's a function on `TIME`, not an aggregated function of `TIME` - should it be using min(`TIME`)?